# Creating a class for checking if the value is null or not in sqlserver

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I will do a lot of thing like this, can someone help me to convert this into a class?

```
private void CheckingForCostID()
{
    //if CostID is exist then error.
    newConnection.ConnectionM();
    SqlCommand cmd = SqlConnectionOLTP.cn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CostCategoryID FROM CostCategory WHERE CostCategoryName =@costcategoryname AND Description =@description";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@costcategoryname", format.SetText(textBoxCostName));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", format.SetText(textBoxCostDescription));
    var costid = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if (costid == null)
    {
        CreateCostCategoryData();
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Cost Category already exist", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    SqlConnectionOLTP.cn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

create 2 classes first for the entity model (CostCategoryModel)
the second class CostCategoryRepository.
In the first your define the structure of you object CostCategory
in the second your define CRUD methods and your utilities methods like

```
public bool Exist(string name, string description){...}
```

then you can use this sample code pattern

```
CostCategoryRepository repo = new CostCategoryRepository();
if(repo.Exist(name,description))
{
...
}else{
...
}
```

Comment: Newing up repositories? Someone hasn't heard of unit testing, dependency injection, transactions, units of work, rollbacks. That is poor advice. It should be an injected `IRepository`, at the very least.

Comment: he must change this piece of code, he not refactoring all project structure my solution is not the best way but resolve his question.